# View passed parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following code snippet, I believe that the $env_vars variable isn't what I expect it to be.

Is there a program / script that I could substitute `docker` with, that would then print the entire command line to terminal? So I can debug what's wrong with my command line and then substitute docker back.

```
docker run \
    -v $filePath:/script \
    -v $uuid:/secrets \
    $env_vars \ 
    $containerImage \
    bash /script/entry.sh
```

So I could have something like

```
someotherexe run \
    -v $filePath:/script \
    -v $uuid:/secrets \
    $env_vars \ 
    $containerImage \
    bash /script/entry.sh
```

and it would print

`someotherexe run -v somepath:/script -v uuid:/secrets etc...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `docker` with `echo`:

```
echo run -v somepath:/script -v uuid:/secrets etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing arguments with `echo` can be misleading, since it just mashes its arguments together with spaces in between. What if one of the arguments contains spaces, or nonprinting characters?

The common way to do this is to put `set -x` before the command, which makes the shell print its favorite (sometimes cryptic) representation of what the command and its arguments are as it executes it.

I also sometimes use something like this:

```
printargs() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "printargs did not get any arguments"
    else
        echo "printargs got $# argument(s):"
        printf "   '%s'\n" "$@" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt
    fi
}
```

This prints nonprinting and non-ASCII characters in weird-but-visible formats. For example:

```
carriagereturn=$'\r'
tab=$'\t'
$ echo –x "spaces and control characters$tab$carriagereturn" 
–x spaces and control characters
$ printargs –x "spaces and control characters$tab$carriagereturn" 
printargs got 3 argument(s):
   'M-bM-^@M-^Sx'
   'spaces and control characters^I^M'
```

What's happening here: for one thing, with the `printargs` version it's clear which spaces are part of arguments, and which are separators *between* arguments. The "`–x`" has a unicode en-dash instead of the plain ASCII hyphen that command-like tools recognize as indicating options; the `cat -vt` part converts its UTF-8 representation into a series of "meta" (M-something) characters. The carriage return and tab are ASCII control characters, specifically control-I and control-M, so it prints them using `^` as shorthand for "control-".